# ListView position on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a problem with my ListView, particular in getView. In my Article object I contain a boolean param and color of object's text depends on the param. But while showing objects on screen text color depends only on two first objects. For example, fisrt obeject contains "true" param, second contains "false" param, and all next obects get their own param in "true"/"false" query, despite all next objects contain only "false" param. 
Other content of objects is fine and is showing good.

This is my getView method. There I marked my Log.d command. And while scrolling I get this, it is just scrolling to third object in a row:

```
08-13 12:20:51.538  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 512  true
08-13 12:20:51.568  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 510  false
08-13 12:20:51.588  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 512  true
08-13 12:20:51.618  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 510  false
08-13 12:20:53.460  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 508  false
08-13 12:20:54.511  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 512  true
08-13 12:20:54.561  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 510  false
08-13 12:20:54.591  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 512  true
08-13 12:20:54.621  21990-21990/md.mybebe.mybebe D/readCUstom﹕ 510  false

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    Typeface robotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),"font/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    Typeface robotoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),"font/Roboto-Bold.ttf");

    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        if (dm.widthPixels <= 480) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_little_width, parent, false);
        } else {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        }

        if (imageLoader == null)    imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.title.setTypeface(robotoBold);

        holder.description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.description.setTypeface(robotoRegular);


        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

   ---->> Log.d("readCUstom", articleItems.get(position).getId()+ "  " +articleItems.get(position).isRead());
    if (articleItems.get(position).isRead()) {
        holder.title.setTextColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
        holder.description.setTextColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    final Button readMoreButton = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.readMoreButton);
    readMoreButton.setTypeface(robotoBold);

    ImageButton toShare = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.toShareButton);
    toAddToFavorite = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.toAddToFavoriteButton);

    SharedPreferences mSettings = activity.getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int userID = mSettings.getInt(LoginActivity.APP_PREFERENCES_PROFILE_ID,0);

    if(articleItems.get(position).isFavorite() & userID != 0) toAddToFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
    else toAddToFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_outline);

    // getting movie data for the row
    final Article article = articleItems.get(position);

    final View view = rowView;

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            readMoreButton.performClick();
            readMoreButton.setPressed(true);
            view.setSelected(true);


        }
    });

    URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(holder.description, rowView.getContext(), activity);
    String html = article.getDescription();
    MyHtmlTagHandler tagHandler = new MyHtmlTagHandler();
    Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(html, p, tagHandler);

    // thumbnail image
    holder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(article.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    holder.title.setText(TextUtils.htmlEncode(article.getTitle()));

    // description
    holder.description.setText(htmlSpan);

    toShare.setOnClickListener(toShareOnClickListener(article, position));
    toAddToFavorite.setOnClickListener(toAddToFavoriteListener(position));

    // button read more
    readMoreButton.setOnClickListener(readMoreClickListener(position));

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adapter reuse view. So, if you chnage the color for some row, when you reuse this row, the color change will stand.

You should always set the color to the desired one. Add this lines :

```
if (articleItems.get(position).isRead()) {
    holder.title.setTextColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
    holder.description.setTextColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
} else {
    holder.title.setTextColor(your default color);
    holder.description.setTextColor(your default color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set other color [else]:

```
  if (articleItems.get(position).isRead()) {
        holder.title.setTextColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
        holder.description.setTextColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
    }else{
        holder.title.setTextColor(Color.argb(100, 100, 0, 0));
        holder.description.setTextColor(Color.argb(100, 100, 0, 0));
   }
```